# "For mail merge to work properly, LibreOffice must be restarted"

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, mail

I have the LibreOffice that comes by default with Ubuntu 2018.04 LTS, all updated.

In Writer's `Tools` menu I noticed this intriguing item called `Mail Merge Wizard…` so I clicked on it. The following popped up:

[image]

OK, no problem, I click `Restart Now`, wait for it to restart, click again and… the same popup comes again. And again.

How to make it work?
My half guess is that I have to install some extra software, maybe LibreOffice Database?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing the following missing packages:

```
apt-get install default-jre libreoffice-java-common \
  libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers
```

Comment: Worked for me, too.